# Real life scenarios testing tool for multiple users

Tags: performance, automation, load

Is there a tool available which would run real life automated scenarios simulating multiple users at the same time.
Basically i need it to start a browser --> Do an action --> logout and close the browser for 10 -20 ..... etc.?

Comment: This is off-topic, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

What about Katalon? https://www.katalon.com/
It is based on Selenium and you can easily perform test suites on different browsers via webdriver. You can execute tests sequential or parallel. It is free to download. You just need to register an account.